# How to filter the simple Subject in a SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, geosparql

I guess I am stuck at the basics with SPARQL. Can someone help ?

I simply wnat to filter all subjects containing "Mountain" of an RDS database.

```
Prefix lgdr:<http://linkedgeodata.org/triplify/> Prefix lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/> 
Select * where { 
?s ?p ?o . 
filter (contains(?s, "Mountain"))
} Limit 1000
```

The query leads to an error:

```
Virtuoso 22023 Error SL001: The SPARQL 1.1 function CONTAINS() needs a string value as first argument
```

Comment: Any luck with `filter (contains(str(?s), "Mountain"))`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You got it. I get an "Transaction timed out", but thats another issue. Thanks for helping. If you like you can answer and I will accept. Good day.

Comment: just wrote the same :-)

Comment: Ah. limiting to 2 for example will work.

Comment: I just posted an answer, it indeed works fine with a smaller `Limit`. :)

Comment: [Assuming that only classes have human-readable names](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org&qtxt=select+*+where+{+%0D%0A++++%3Fs+a+owl%3AClass+.%0D%0A++++filter+(contains(str(%3Fs)%2C+%22Mountain%22))+.%0D%0A++++%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A}&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0). There are also things like `<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/MountainPass/key/natural/value/mountain_pass>` though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to "work" using:

```
Prefix lgdr:<http://linkedgeodata.org/triplify/> Prefix lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/> 
Select * where { 
?s ?p ?o . 
filter (contains(str(?s), "Mountain"))
} Limit 1000
```

Note the additional `str` in the query.

However, that results in

```
Virtuoso S1T00 Error SR171: Transaction timed out
```

and I am not sure how to deal with that.

But in principle in works: When you use

```
Limit 1
```

you get

```
s   p   o
http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/MountainRescue    http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type     http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class
```